# Deserialization and throw exception for required property when it is null

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I'm probably missing something.
I'd like to test behavior when an API call response returns a property of null and I would like to throw an exception when that happens.

I have a `Form` object as follow

```cs
public class Form
{
    [Required]
    public string Html { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have initialized an object

```cs
var myData = new
{
    Json = "foo",
};

string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Form>(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath));
```

I was expecting to have an exception since the `Html` property is `required` and not `nullable`,
but actually getting the object as

```
{
    Html = null, 
    Json = foo,
    Name = null
}
```

I have tried to use `JsonSerializerSettings` as follows but this actually throws an exception only when there is an additional unwanted property and not when there's a missing one.

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings config = new JsonSerializerSettings { MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include};
var res =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Form>(json,config);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]`.

```cs
public class Form
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Html { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yqbAoU)

While `[Required]` attribute is for [Data Annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-6.0).

---

**Reference**

[JsonPropertyAttribute required](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm)